# Checking build system type... ./config.guess: unable to guess system type

Tags: c++, linux

Пытаюсь запустить скрипт ./configure. В ответ получаю сообщение с ошибкой и нижеследующим текстом:

```
This script, last modified 2009-06-10, has failed to recognize
the operating system you are using. It is advised that you
download the most up to date version of the config scripts from

  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.guess;hb=HEAD
and
  http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=config.git;a=blob_plain;f=config.sub;hb=HEAD

If the version you run (./config.guess) is already up to date, please
send the following data and any information you think might be
pertinent to <config-patches@gnu.org> in order to provide the needed
information to handle your system.

config.guess timestamp = 2009-06-10
```

Что с этим нужно делать?

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка говорит о том, что скрипт config.guess устарел и предлагает закачать новую версию. Нужно ее скачать по ссылке указанной в сообщение, переписать поверх старой версии и заново запустить ./configure. Если ОС уже учтена в скрипте все пойдет правильно, иначе нужно читать доки и вручную прописывать опции.